# Convert string into a key

Tags: python

I am getting the below output:

```
{'ACME MARKETS INC': ['Customer service: 1 (877) 723-3929',
                      'Headquarters: Malvern, PA',
                      'Number of locations: 162',
                      'Founded: 1891, Philadelphia, PA',
                      'President: Jim Perkins',
                      'Parent organizations: Albertsons, Jewel, and American '
                      'Stores',
                      'Founders: Samuel Robinson and Robert Crawford'],
 'RITE AID OF OHIO INC': ['Address: 7844 OH-45, Lisbon, OH 44432',
                          'Hours: Open ⋅ Closes 10PM',
                          'Phone: (330) 424-7743',
                          'Headquarters: Camp Hill, PA',
                          'Founded: 1971',
                          'Parent organization: Rite Aid']}
```

I want to create the array into key-value pairs so that I can make in df:

```
{'ACME MARKETS INC': ['Customer service': '1 (877) 723-3929',
                      'Headquarters': 'Malvern, PA',
                      'Number of locations': '162',
                      'Founded': '1891, Philadelphia, PA',
                      'President': 'Jim Perkins',
                      'Parent organizations': 'Albertsons, Jewel, and American '
                      'Stores',
                      'Founders': 'Samuel Robinson and Robert Crawford'],
 'RITE AID OF OHIO INC': ['Address': '7844 OH-45, Lisbon, OH 44432',
                          'Hours': 'Open ⋅ Closes 10PM',
                          'Phone': '(330) 424-7743',
                          'Headquarters': 'Camp Hill, PA',
                          'Founded': '1971',
                          'Parent organization': 'Rite Aid']}
```

CODE:

```
import requests
import bs4
import pprint


def parse(search):
    
    url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + search  # this should be url-encoded
    request_result=requests.get( url )
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request_result.text,"html.parser")
    heading_object = soup.find_all( 'div', {'class': 'AVsepf'})
    return [x.getText() for x in heading_object]
    info_list = []
    for x in heading_object:
        info_list.append(x.getText())
    return info_list
      
results = {}

# ACME MARKETS INC
# RITE AID OF OHIO INC
for pharm in range(2):
    pharm = input('enter the name of a pharmacy')
    print(pharm)
    results[pharm] = parse(pharm)

pprint.pprint(results)
```

Comment: Hi but this is not resulting in accurate output. Its  giving same values for both the names

Comment: the scarpping part of the code is not relevant to question, you should remove it.

Comment: In `parse` definition the code below `return [x.getText() for x in heading_object]` will never be executed.

Comment: The output format is a bit strange has it does not have any parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

The output need to be set into a dictionnary for key:value reference.

```
st = {'ACME MARKETS INC': ['Customer service: 1 (877) 723-3929', 'Headquarters: Malvern, PA', 'Number of locations: 162', 'Founded: 1891, Philadelphia, PA', 'President: Jim Perkins', 'Parent organizations: Albertsons, Jewel, and American ' 'Stores', 'Founders: Samuel Robinson and Robert Crawford'], 'RITE AID OF OHIO INC': ['Address: 7844 OH-45, Lisbon, OH 44432', 'Hours: Open ⋅ Closes 10PM', 'Phone: (330) 424-7743', 'Headquarters: Camp Hill, PA', 'Founded: 1971', 'Parent organization: Rite Aid']}
dic = dict()
for key in st.keys():
    for val in st.get(key) :
        dic[val.split(":")[0]] = val.split(":")[1]
    st[key] = [dic]
    dic = {}
st
```

output:

```
{'ACME MARKETS INC': [{'Customer service': ' 1 (877) 723-3929',
   'Headquarters': ' Malvern, PA',
   'Number of locations': ' 162',
   'Founded': ' 1891, Philadelphia, PA',
   'President': ' Jim Perkins',
   'Parent organizations': ' Albertsons, Jewel, and American Stores',
   'Founders': ' Samuel Robinson and Robert Crawford'}],
 'RITE AID OF OHIO INC': [{'Address': ' 7844 OH-45, Lisbon, OH 44432',
   'Hours': ' Open ⋅ Closes 10PM',
   'Phone': ' (330) 424-7743',
   'Headquarters': ' Camp Hill, PA',
   'Founded': ' 1971',
   'Parent organization': ' Rite Aid'}]}
```

Comment: That's not the correct output. You've simply repeated the Rite Aid data, and don't have the Acme Markets data at all.

Comment: Additionally, [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments.

Comment: I've updated the answer. @MattDMo

Comment: This is not the asked for output. The asked for output does not have any parenthesis.